# Images significantly slowing Rspec request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

So, my request spec is being slowed down tremendously by the presence of two small images (3k size each). The same page has two much larger images, one over 700k, but it doesn't have any problem with those. Here's the code (in slim, which I hate, but whatever):

```
.row.columns#banner
  = image_tag image_url("banner-tail-left.png"), class: 'banner-tail-left'
  .banner-text WELCOME
  = image_tag image_url("banner-tail-right.png"), class: 'banner-tail-right'
```

And here are the test speeds:

Both images showing:

```
Finished in 4.01 seconds
Finished in 3.27 seconds
Finished in 3.55 seconds
Finished in 3.5 seconds
```

Both images hidden with unless Rails.env.test?:

```
Finished in 1.56 seconds
Finished in 1.38 seconds
Finished in 1.23 seconds
Finished in 1.2 seconds
```

With just one of either of those images showing, the times are the same slowness as if they're both showing. If I replace the two image paths with other image paths, it's fast. Any idea what might be causing this? Is there a way to tell Rspec to ignore all images?

Comment: Show the code for tests which are slow.

Comment: The test code can't possibly matter. I can put this same image tag on ANY page, and the tests that test that page slows down the same amount. Though it does appear to only slow down the first one if I'm running multiple tests on the same page.

Comment: Are you using capybara, phantomjs, selenium, etc. or any other gems for this particular test?

Comment: @JayDorsey No, just Rspec request specs. Is it necessary to mention capybara, phantomjs, selenium, etc.? It's a request spec, not a feature spec. Uhm... FactoryGirl.

Comment: If would only be relevant if you were using them. Since the test isn't shown, nor your helper files/configuration my question was a low hanging fruit question meant to rule out a potential misconfiguration. Only other thing that comes to mind for debugging is looking at the `test.rb` config file for your asset settings (if someone changed them). Also, spring comes to mind

Comment: @JayDorsey Yeah, it really is just a very basic request test. In fact, I just tried changing it to a completely static page, with a test that is just get "/path" and expect(true).to be true, and it's still doing it. The image files doing this are pngs, and they're in the base images folder, but there are other pngs in the base images folder that aren't slowing my tests down. I see nothing in the rails_helper file that looks related to assets. Dunno about spring.

Comment: Very interesting behavior. I don't think there is a way to tell RSpec to ignore loading images (you can do this when you're using Capybara, which is another reason I asked earlier). Without being able to inspect the images or the code this is likely to be difficult to troubleshoot. Since you tried replacing with different images already (and it was fast again), I would focus on inspecting those images. Maybe they're JPG files named as PNG or have something applied that slows down the rendering (alpha channel?) I'm not quite sure if the asset pipeline comes into play or not with these tests...

Comment: When you replace the images with the 'fast' ones, are both fast and slow images in the same directory? Also, could you try logging `image_url("banner-tail-left.png")` (or whatever you change the name to), in case there is some weirdness where the spec attempts to use an image on a CDN rather than locally.

Comment: Given when you swap out the images, it's fixed, I doubt it's rspec. Not saying this will fix it but we had a similar experience with some asset pngs having a hidden alpha mask layer due to the program that generated them. No idea why it was there, once we removed it all was well.

Comment: @JayDorsey - Nope, they have the correct extensions.

Comment: @Phil - 1. Yes, they are in the same directory. 2. Using pry, I checked out image_url("banner-tail-left.png") right before it rendered. Interestingly, calling that method with that filename is where the slowness is. Also, RSpec image_urls are example.com urls. "http://www.example.com/assets/banner-tail-left-c801e1b3e8c8ba4f5fee818d8dac1f9ca057e0fdd8f218b3e8f175a71b274639.png" - Fast image: "http://www.example.com/assets/logo-hssh-hero-61c6101d7a839773034d58393edafe02640c30f36172416ff17816df2b7c8f1e.png"

Comment: the example.com is the default absolute path DNS (_url helpers) in rails if you don't explicitly set it in your application.rb. You can handle this behavior by using the relative routing helpers that end in _path

Comment: Can you post a link to one or more of the slow images? Would like to test this locally from my machine and see if I can recreate it. If you use one of the other helpers, like `image_path`, is that also slow? Also, using `image_tag` + `image_url`, I thought the tag knew where to look in the asset pipeline. Are both necessary?

Comment: @JayDorsey You're 100% correct about the image tag. I was just blindly following the pattern that was there without thinking about it. :) It didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: @JayDorsey Here are image links: https://imgur.com/RkwBOGm  https://imgur.com/PCczgnQ https://imgur.com/r1VWRHs https://imgur.com/CgxFp0n - on Friday, I added two more to the app with the same problem from the same designer. I might need to try and contact him to see how he's creating them.

Comment: can you share version of rails and rspec please?

Comment: Rails 4.2.9, RSpec-rails 3.4.2, RSpec 3.4.0

Comment: Do you use capybara with any kind of browser driver? what does your test file look like?

Comment: The app has Capybara installed, but it is not being used with these tests. And I just tried commenting out everything in both rails_helper and spec_helper (including Capybara), but that didn't change anything.

Comment: I tested by using an Rails 5 application (not a test though), but those images look normal/fine. Running an asset precompile, they're also fine (not slow to compile). Have you ruled out slim being an issue? If you can test by replacing an ERB or HAML template to rule out that could rule out a templating bug. Also, you might try running the images thru tinypng (I know they're small already) because it does make a minor optimization. Running `file` on a known good & bad png should  identify differences with format. Very interesting problem and would love to see the solution if you figure it out

Comment: It's only a problem in tests. The pages load totally fine normally. I'll check out some of your other ideas what I have a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping all image metadata with imagemagick (convert -strip), or any way of "remaking" if with gimp.

Comment: Nice idea, but this did not work. Converting to jpg also did not work.